# How do I use ExcelDNA to select a cell?

Tags: excel-dna

I want to force the focus onto a particular cell, which I have a reference for via XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfCaller). I know how to do this in VSTO, but is there a way to do it with ExcelDNA?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be to use the COM Automation interface, as you would from VBA or VSTO. Just be sure to use the `Application` object you get from `ExcelDnaUtil.Application` as your root. To convert from the `ExcelReference` that you received from `xlfCaller` to a COM `Range` object, you might try (this is the VB.NET version):

```
Private Function ReferenceToRange(ByVal xlRef As ExcelReference) As Object 
     Dim strAddress As String = XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, xlRef, True) 
     ReferenceToRange = ExcelDnaUtil.Application.Range(strAddress) 
End Function
```

If you want to stick with the C API, you'd first have to select the right sheet, then the actual cell. So you might have:

```
string myCellSheet = (string)XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlSheetNm, myCell);
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcWorkbookSelect, new object[] { myCellSheet });
XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcFormulaGoto, myCell);
```

You won't be able to change the selection in a worksheet function, so I presume you are calling this from a macro or ribbon handler.

Comment: Thanks for the response! In C# I can't access the range method on ExcelDnaUtil.Application because it it of type object. What type should I cast it to?

Comment: Oh, I got it, I just use dynamic :D

Comment: the line 'XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlfReftext, xlRef, True)' is bombing out. I am not intending to change the selection from a worksheet function, but I am getting the xlfCaller from inside a worksheet function. Could this be a problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's possible to do with ExcelDNA:

```
var activeCell = new ExcelReference(5, 5);
ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro(() => XlCall.Excel(XlCall.xlcSelect, activeCell));
```

"ExcelAsyncUtil.QueueAsMacro" could be skipped, it's depends on context from which you call Excel command. If you call it from another Excel function - you should wrap it up with QueueAsMacro